# How to sort LINQ / Entity Framework query by grandchild property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am running into a problem with a LINQ query. I have the following data structure (Entity Framework classes mapped to a SQL Server DB):

Event has an EventBlocks property with 0 or more EventBlock objects as children.
EventBlock has a Details property with 0 or more EventBlockDetail objects as children.
EventBlockDetail has a DetailDate and a StartTime.

I need to show the next 3 upcoming events on a website. Sort order is determined by the event's earliest start date and time, which is stored in Event -> EventBlock -> EventBlockDetail. If the next 2 or 3 upcoming EventBlockDetails happen to belong to the same event, that event should only be shown once, and another event should show up in the top 3.

Is there any way to accomplish this with a single LINQ query, so I won't have to do a lot of looping and comparing after getting ALL the event data from the database?

To illustrate what I am trying to do, here is a fictitious query, which will obviously not work because the first OrderBy doesn't know which property to order by.

```
var result = this.Context.Events.Where(
    e => e.WebsiteId == websiteId && 
        e.EventBlocks.All(
            b => b.Details.All(
                d => d.DetailDate >= DateTime.Now
            )
        )
    ).OrderBy( 
        e => e.EventBlocks.OrderBy(
            b => eb.Details.Min(d => d.DetailDate)).ThenBy(
            b => eb.Details.Min(d => d.StartTime))
    ).Take(nrOfEvents).ToList();
```

Comment: why you have added two orderBy ?

Comment: Why isn't the date and time stored in one column?  What types are the `DetailDate` and the `StartTime`?

Comment: The two OrderBy were just an attempt to illustrate I was trying to order by a grandchild and I was so stuck on this I couldn't think of a better way to explain that.

DetailDate is a DateTime and StartTime is a TimeSpan. I don't know why the decision was made to store them separately. It's an existing system that's several years old already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select the event and the earliest date and time by ordering all the events details by the date and time and taking the first one.  Then you can use that detail for filtering and ordering the events.

```
var result = Context.Events
    .Where(e => e.WebsiteId == websiteId)
    .Select(e => new 
    { 
        Event = e, 
        StartDetails = e.EventBlocks
            .SelectMany(b => b.Details)
            .OrderBy(d => d.DetailDate) 
            .ThenBy(d => d.StartTime)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Where(x => x.StartDetails.DetailDate >= DateTime.Now)
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDetails.DetailDate)
    .ThenBy(x => x.StartDetails.StartTime)
    .Take(nrOfEvents)
    .Select(x => x.Event)
    .ToList();
```

Note that the `x => x.StartDetails.DetailDate >= DateTime.Now` filter would potentially remove something that hasn't started yet if the `DetailDate` has time truncated.  In which case you might actually want to filter on `DateTime.Today` but also filter if the time is before the current time if the date is today.  For example if the detail has a date of 2019-09-25 (presumably stored with a time of midnight) then comparing to 2019-09-25 at 8am (if that's the current date time) would fail even if the detail's start time is after 8am.

So maybe that filter should be the following assuming `StartTime` is a `Timespan` or something similar based on whatever `StartTime` is.

```
.Where(x => x.StartDetails.DetailDate > DateTime.Today ||
            (x.StartDetails.DetailDate == DateTime.Today &&
            x.StartDetails.StartTime >= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay))
```

This would make more sense and be a more simple query if the date and time where stored in one column instead of two.

Comment: As I understand the requirements, the where clause should be before the first select and just filter out all past events since we are always looking at only the events in the future, not event groupings where the first event is in the future.  However, your answer totally addresses the problem presented so +1.

Comment: @Grax This is all going to be turned into SQL so it doesn't matter if the date/time filtering is before or after.  It's just easier to express that filtering after when you have the earliest date/time to work with.

Comment: Not my best wording, but my point was that you shouldn't be filtering on earliest date, but instead filter out all prior events before doing anything else.  As written, you are filtering out any websiteId where at the earliest event is in the past.

Comment: The OP's code will filter out all the events that have any details before the current date/time.  That's the same as just filtering on the earliest one.

Comment: Brilliant! I marked the solution as the Correct Answer. I did get an error message that .First() can't be used in the middle of a query, only at the end, and that I had to replace it with FirstOrDefault(). Other than that, it completely solves my problem. Thanks so much.